# Removing All instances of specific delegate from multicast delegates

Tags: c#, multicastdelegate

**Note:** I'm writing this to have documented answers on my question because I frequently find myself having to manually research this

I'm looking for an efficient deterministic way to remove all instances of a delegate from a multicast delegate.  Take tis code for example:

```
 Func<int> outputProvider = null;

 Func<int> valueProvider1 = () => 1;
 Func<int> valueProvider2 = () => 2;
 Func<int> valueProvider3 = () => 3;
 
 outputProvider += valueProvider1; 
 outputProvider += valueProvider2;
 outputProvider += valueProvider3;
 outputProvider += valueProvider3;
 
 outputProvider -= valueProvider3;

 var value = outputProvider.Invoke();
 Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value);
```

Even though I removed provider 3 the output is still 3,  is there a simple way to remove all instances of a delegate?

Comment: Where do you remove, I don't see it

Comment: @Charlieface oops copy error thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist?view=net-5.0 to examine the set of delegates yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty self-explanatory:

```cs
outputProvider = (Func<int>) Delegate.RemoveAll(outputProvider, valueProvider3);
```